Как сбросить настройки или просто настроить Idle3?
Дано:::

Есть linux open suse leap 2024 года на моем компе.
Установлен Idle3 и python3 на моем компе.
Все бы хорошо!

Проблема:::

Чего-то нажал не того (сtrl + F1 ... FN или сtrl +1... N), и в результате, когда нажимаю на backspace , то удаляется вся строка.
Не работает нумерация строк (enumerate).
Не работает ctrl+z. а также обратка (ctrl+y).
Переустановка idle3 тоже не помогает.

Задача:
Помогите настроить: всё это, или сбросить!

Конфиг idle лежит в директории ~/.idlerc. Чтобы сбросить настройки idle, достаточно эту директорию удалить

Переоткрыто по просьбе автора для самоответа.

Решение:

Зайти в приложение plasma-discover (discover-менеджер приложений). Оттуда выбрать 2-ую же по счету такую же (idle3).
В этой версии есть: пронумеровать строки и все работает.
Зашел сюда ~/.idlerc. Удалить все файлы. И настройки сбрасываются.
Нашел Undo: ctrl+z , оказывается redo: ctrl+shift+z - в настройках горячих клавиш.

Теперь все работает!

@Dmitry Скажите разработчикам, у них какой-то трабл: когда на английском стеке пишешь `````` или `` там что-то не приключается, и нельзя создать вопрос: гемор полный, может тему поднять на мете?

я такой же пользователь как и вы, у меня нет никаких разработчиков. енСО и руСО не связаны в управлении между собой (глобально). Все вопросы про енСО направлять туда, в том числе и на мету
